# How to execute custom code before new connection is created from datasource

Tags: java, datasource

I need to execute custom code before new connection is created in data source. I am using BasicDataSource for connection pooling. I am using Spring jdbcTemplate with BasicDataSource so I am not calling getConnection() manually.

I need to execute custom code before connection in order to re-login with kerberos credential for hive jdbc.

Is it possible to do something like this?

I am creating connection with below sample code

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass)

    return dataSource;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Anything is possible.  How easy it is and how you should go about it depends a lot on how you're constructing your app.  Are you using a framework?  Any kind of dependency injection?  More specifically, can you explain how your BasicDataSource objects are configured and instantiated?  What is managing the connection pool?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code used to create datasource

Comment: just create a kerberosLogin() method and call it before the datasource.getConnection() line, or inside your dataSource() method. I don't know if im understanding the issue thou.... Hm..?

Comment: You are getting this right Aran, Currently I am also doing same thing. i.e. calling kerberos login before running any query in each functions. 

I am not getting connection manually by calling getConnection() method as I  am using BasicDataSource with Spring jdbcTemplate so connection pool is not managed by me. I want to call this kerberos login method somehow while connection is created in connection pool

Comment: so if i understand correctly, you are able to change the Database creation method (the code you posted), but not the connection creation, right(getConnection is out of your bounds)?